# What are valid connection strings for SSMS login box?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, connectivity, sqlcmd

What are valid connection strings for SSMS login box?

Every once in a while I will have to connect to an instance of SQL Server with some specific configuration setting or in a DMZ where no host names are available or I'll have to connect to the Dedicated Admin Connection (DAC) via SSMS or SQLCMD. Because I rarely connect to a SQL Server via specific port or with the DAC, I'll tend to forget what the exact syntax options are to get a connection up and running. I'll then have to search the internet *again* for the umpteenth time to retrieve the exact connection strings and will regularly be frustrated that I can't find the information required.

## Research

I'll read all the questions and answers previously posted on Serverfault, Stackoverflow, and DBA.

### Serverfault

[1] [DAC connection port SQL Server 2005 SP3](https://serverfault.com/q/154036/145804)
[2] [Remote SQL server connection failure](https://serverfault.com/q/123580/145804)
[3] [SQL Server 2008 R2 remote connection](https://serverfault.com/q/402924/145804)

### Stackoverflow

[4] [How to specify a port number in SQL Server connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5294721/1820861)

### DBA

[5] [DAC connection error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/95887/15356)

### Microsoft

Additionally, I'll search the Microsoft site for relevant articles:

[6] [How to configure SQL Server to listen on a specific port](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/823938)
[7] [Configure the Windows Firewall to Allow SQL Server Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx)
[8] [Surface Area Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161956.aspx)
[9] [How to configure SQL server to listen on different ports on different IP addresses?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlblog/2009/07/17/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-listen-on-different-ports-on-different-ip-addresses/)
[10] [Configure a Server to Listen on a Specific TCP Port (SQL Server Configuration Manager)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx)
[11] [Diagnostic Connection for Database Administrators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189595.aspx)

### Brent Ozar

And Kendra Little has an article for some interesting aspects of DAC.
[12] [The Dedicated Admin Connection: Why You Want It, When You Need It, and How To Tell Who’s Using It](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/08/dedicated-admin-connection-why-want-when-need-how-tell-whos-using/)

*On a side note: sometimes the DAC connection is also referred to as the ADMIN connection.*

I find that in the end there is never an actual summary of simple connection strings to input into an SSMS login box, nor what to add to a SQLCMD.

This question and the following answers are intended to sum up what I found so far and to put the information into one single knowledge base article.

## Actual Question

Given the following settings for a SQL Server Standard Edition:

```
Servername.....:    SERVERNAME
IP address.....:    123.1.2.3

1st instance (default instance):
CNAME/Alias....:    SERVERNAME-I01
Name...........:    MSSQLSERVER
Port...........:    1433 (TCP)
IP address.....:    123.1.2.3
DAC Port.......:    1434 (TCP)

2nd instance (default ip & port configuration according to [7]):
CNAME/Alias....:    SERVERNAME-I02
Name...........:    Instance2
Port...........:    dynamic (TCP)
IP address.....:    123.1.2.3
DAC port.......:    dynamic (TCP)

3rd instance (dedicated IP and port):
CNAME/Alias....:    SERVERNAME-I03
Name...........:    Instance3
Port...........:    1433 (TCP)
IP address.....:    123.1.2.4
DAC port.......:    dynamic (TCP)

Browser Service:    1434 (UDP)
Browser service:    ON
```

...what are valid connection strings for each instance that I can enter into the SSMS login box

1. ...with the host name?
2. ...an alias (CNAME)?
3. ...with an ip address?
4. ...for a "Dedicated Admin Connection" (DAC aka ADMIN:)?

## Assumptions

1. The server firewall is either deactivated or configured according to the Microsoft documentation mentioned in [6](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/823938), [7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx) or [8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161956.aspx). This is also true for any network firewall inside the LAN (including the connection to a DMZ server).
2. The additional instances, apart from the default instance, have manually been configured to listen on different IP addresses according to [9](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlblog/2009/07/17/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-listen-on-different-ports-on-different-ip-addresses/) and in this example have been configured to listen on fixed ports [10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx).
3. In some cases DAC will have been enable according to [11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189595.aspx) and [12](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/08/dedicated-admin-connection-why-want-when-need-how-tell-whos-using/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various possibilities and I will try to answer them according to the numbered questions.

Valid connection strings for the SSMS login box are:

## 1st instance

1. Using the host name

   - `SERVERNAME`
   - `SERVERNAME,1433`
2. Using the CNAME/Alias

   - `SERVERNAME-I01`
   - `SERVERNAME-I01,1433`
3. Using the IP address

   - `123.1.2.3`
   - `123.1.2.3,1433`
4. For the Dedicated Admin Connection (DAC); depends on Browser Service status

   a) Browser Service ON

   - `ADMIN:SERVERNAME`
   - `ADMIN:SERVERNAME-I01`
   - `ADMIN:123.1.2.3`

   b) Browser Service OFF

   - `SERVERNAME,1434`
   - `SERVERNAME-I01,1434`
   - `123.1.2.3,1434`

## 2nd instance

Because the 2nd instance has a dynamic port for the SQL Server instance and a dynamic port for DAC, the ports have to be retrieved from the ERROR log file in advance before connecting to the SQL Server. See [7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx) for more information. In this example I will assume port 63390 is used for the SQL Server instance and port 63389 is used for the Dedicated Admin Connection. Microsoft recommends to fix the IP port, thus allowing you to properly configure a firewall [6](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/823938).

1. Using the host name

   - `SERVERNAME\Instance2` (Browser Service ON)
   - `SERVERNAME,63390` (Browser Service OFF)
2. Using the CNAME\Alias

   - `SERVERNAME-I02` (Browser Service ON)
   - `SERVERNAME-I02,63390` (Browser Service OFF)
3. Using the IP address

   - `123.1.2.3,63390` (Browser Service is ON or OFF)
     *Using the IP address without port, would connect you to the default instance*
4. For the Dedicated Admin Connection (DAC); really depends on Browser Service status

   a) Browser Service ON

   - `ADMIN:SERVERNAME\Instance2`
   - `ADMIN:SERVERNAME-I02\Instance2`
   - `ADMIN:123.1.2.3\Instance2`
     *Always requires instance name, because the CNAME or IP address references the same IP address as the default standard instance*

   b) Browser Service OFF

   - `SERVERNAME,63389`
   - `SERVERNAME-I01,63389`
   - `123.1.2.3,63389`

## 3rd instance

1. Using the host name

   - `SERVERNAME\Instance3`
     *Because this instance is using the same SQL Server port as the default instance, but a different IP address, the `SERVERNAME,1433` notation would not work. You would be connected to the default instance.*
2. Using the CNAME/Alias

   - `SERVERNAME-I03` (Browser Service ON)
   - `SERVERNAME-I03,1433` (Browser Service OFF)
3. Using the IP address

   - `123.1.2.4`
   - `123.1.2.4,1435`
4. For the Dedicated Admin Connection (DAC); depends on Browser Service status

   a) Browser Service ON

   - `ADMIN:SERVERNAME\Instance3`
   - `ADMIN:SERVERNAME-I03` (works because the CNAME references a dedicated IP address)
   - `ADMIN:123.1.2.4`

   b) Browser Service OFF

   - `SERVERNAME,63389` (works because the port references a dedicated port for DAC)
   - `SERVERNAME-I01,63389` (works because the CNAME and port reference a dedicated instance/DAC)
   - `123.1.2.4,63389`

---

### Browser Service

If the browser service is DISABLED or has not been started, then connections cannot be routed to the relevant port. In this case the DAC port has to be retrieved from the ERRORLOG file of the instance. You should find a line with something like *Dedicated admin connection support was established for listening remotely on port 63389.* for the DAC port. This port number is the port the DAC will listen on. You are required to supply the relevant port for the Dedicated Admin connection and the corresponding port for the SQL Server connection if your Browser Service is turned off. You do not have to add the instance name to the connection string when using the port, because the port is reserved for the instance.

In short the Browser Service is responsible for converting instance names to ports. If the Browser Service is not running, then you have to supply the port instead of the instance name.

---

## Reference Material

- [Logging In to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/logging-in-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) (Microsoft | Docs | SQL Server)

Comment: You mention both "alias" and "CNAME". Are you talking about a CNAME within DNS? Or an alias with SQL Server Configuration Manager (and/or SQL Client Network Utility)?

Comment: I'm talking about a CNAME entry in DNS. Could be a HOST entry too. I specifically didn't mention SQL Server Network Aliases.

Comment: Then I'm confused about the first bullet item under #2 for the 2nd instance. SERVERNAME-I02 would be a CNAME pointing to SERVERNAME. But a CNAME can't incorporate a port, so without specifying either the instance name or the port in the connection string, I don't see how it'll get connected. Even with the browser service running, it would need the name of the instance in order to map it to a port, right?

Comment: Wrong. Each instance is configured to a specific IP address (see question). So the CNAME `SERVERNAME-I02` points to a specific IP address (`123.1.2.3`) which is on the same server, but reserved for an instance.

Comment: Checking the question again, I see that both the 1st and 2nd instances are using 123.1.2.3. If SERVERNAME-I01 and SERVERNAME-I02 both resolve to 123.1.2.3, then connection strings pointing to those two CNAMEs would end up at the same place -- port 1433 of 123.1.2.3. I don't see how the server would be able to differentiate them.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I'll double check my question and answer again and get back. I did write in my question in the assumptions that: _The additional instances, apart from the default instance, have manually been configured to listen on different IP addresses according to 9 and in this example have been configured to listen on fixed ports 10._ Might be a typo.