# How to remotely connect SQL Server 2016. Since we have 2012 and 2016 in same server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016, instance

#### Issue

I am not able to connect to a SQL Server 2016 instance on a remote system/server.

#### My Existing Environment

1. Windows Server 2012
2. SQL Server 2012 and 2016 installed on same server

I tried to enable a firewall rule for SQL Server 2016 with port 1433. But it is not working.

Same thing I tried with SQL Server 2012 it is all working fine.

#### Settings I Have Tried

1. Enabled remote connection in SQL server.
2. Created Firewall rule to browse SQL Server.
3. Enabled TCP Port.
4. Enabled default port 1433.

#### Error Message I Am Receiving

[image: Error Message - Connect to Server]

It would be great if anybody could help me with this.

Comment: Try checking on services.msc if both the SQL SERVER 2012 and 2016 are running

Comment: It's trying to establish a Named Pipes connection. The SQL Server TCP settings/port are irrelevant if that's the type of connection you want to establish

Comment: @jun drie, Both the services are running.

Comment: you can't have both SQL Server listening on same port 1433. Use different port no or use dynamic port

Comment: Yea I tried with different port also

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever, he is not trying to connect via Named Pipes. All the protocols are tried in order Shared Memory, TCP/IP, Named Pipes. The last one just reports the error

Comment: @Sharad you'll find a *lot* of duplicate questions. There's nothing special about SQL Server 2016, even Express. It's either firewall, wrong address or wrong *instance name*. If mulitple versions are installed on the same server you probably need the `SQL Server Browser` service as well, otherwise you'll have to specify different ports during installation

Comment: @Sharad what does the *connection string* look like? Can you connect to the database from a Remote  desktop session on the server itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable remote connections for SQL Server Express 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012)

Comment: @Sharad check the duplicate. There are many similar but this has 400 upvotes and several good answers. It explains about SQL Server Browser, ports, protocols etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to open firewall rule for UDP 1434 SQL Browser port. Be sure SQL 2012 and 2016 don't use same TCP port (1433). If multiple instance on same machine they should be configured to use separate TCP port.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `named instance` so if you want to use its name, `SQL Server Browser` should run.
But the correct exception in Firewall still should be created so you should know the correct port number.

Now open SQL Server `error log` (in Notepad, via SSMS under Management node or by using `xp_readerrorlog`), one of the first rows in the `error log` reports the port on which your instance is listening on. For this port you should create the exception.

The error cited on one hand says that the instance cannot be found, if it is so finding the correct port number will resolve your problem.

On the other hand it says "the user name or password is incorrect", if this is true, you'll see it among the last rows of `error log`.

So in any case, the key is in the `error log`.

Comment: I cant see any error log. Because I am trying to connect in remote machine.

Comment: But how could you configure SQL Server port and firewall exception if you cannot access this remote pc? I suppose you used RDP

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at my extensive question and answer regarding

- [What are valid connection strings for SSMS login box?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/134499/15356).

Depending on circumstances not yet aware to you, you might have better chances of connecting to your instance using a different variation of the `servername\instancename:port` string.

Possible variations instead of `Server\Instance` would be:

- `123.1.2.4,1433` <== using the SQL server's **IP address** and **instance port number**
- `B4EDEV01,1433` <== using the SQL Server's **host name** and **instance port number**
- `ADMIN:123.1.2.4\SQLEXP2016` <== DAC connection with **IP address** and **port number**

Depending on your network settings in the SQL Server Configuration Manager for the 2016 instance, you might have to use different port numbers and/or IP addresses.